# Home page merely shows a directory listing

Tags: php, .htaccess

I was trying to load a php file in html such that the menu is loaded dynamically from an external file.Hence I used the code :

```
      <ul id="navlist">
<!-- Include header.php here -->
<?php include("header.php"); ?>
<!-- Normal HTML code begins here -->
</ul>
<br />
```

and

Based upon my research online ,I found that I will need to modify my .htaccess file to include these two lines

```
AddType application/x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
AddHandler x-httpd-php .php .htm .html
```

To force the server to parse the html at the server level ,after doing that ,when I go to the site,I just see a directory listing as opposed to the site.

Any inputs would be great.

Thanks

Comment: Usually you must have index.php file in a directory. This index file is used when no other file specified in URL.

Comment: AFAIK, addHandler for php files should already been include in your modules.d folder. You should not need to edit your .htaccess for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see the directory listing because you don't have any "directory index" file.

You should also disable directory listing.

Some [documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/core.html#options) for you

Comment: thanks for the response ,so the situation is I do have a  placeholder page in the main site which has a directory Index to it as
DirectoryIndex default.php but I am actually trying to view the contents of a subdomain page where I am checking to see if the php is rendered properly before I actually host it on the main site (guess you could call it a test bed) ,so I am now confused if I need a .htaccess within the subdomain  page or not ?

Comment: if you try to access a basic file (txt/html file) ? like i said you should disable "directory listing".

Comment: so if you have DirectoryIndex default.php , you need a file name default.php in your DocumentRoot directory.

Comment: Yes ,I am trying to access a basic html file which has some php in it ,hence the need for the above alterations to the .htaccess file  

I made the change to disable directory listing using Options -Indexes ,so that works now but now I am getting this error message 

Forbidden
You don't have permission to access / on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Comment: Forbidden message is ok, basic file is NO php in it. If it's working, it's mean php is not well configured on your server.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/4942/discussion-between-racar-and-mervin)